# slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

```
def generate_image_folder_structure(frames, masks, frames_list, masks_list):
    '''Function to save images in the appropriate folder directories 
        Inputs: 
            frames - frame tensor dataset
            masks - mask tensor dataset
            frames_list - frame file paths
            masks_list - mask file paths
    '''
    #Create iterators for frames and masks
    frame_batches = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(frames)  # outside of TF Eager, we would use make_one_shot_iterator
    mask_batches = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(masks)
    
    #Iterate over the train images while saving the frames and masks in appropriate folders
    dir_name='train'
    for file in zip(frames_list[:-round(0.2*len(frames_list))],masks_list[:-round(0.2*len(masks_list))]):
        
        
        #Convert tensors to numpy arrays # khawar
        frame = frame_batches.next(g).numpy().astype(np.uint8)
        mask = mask_batches.next(g).numpy().astype(np.uint8)
        
        #Convert numpy arrays to images
        frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
        mask = Image.fromarray(mask)
        
        #Save frames and masks to correct directories
        frame.save(DATA_PATH+'{}_frames/{}'.format(dir_name,dir_name)+'/'+file[0])
        mask.save(DATA_PATH+'{}_masks/{}'.format(dir_name,dir_name)+'/'+file[1])
    
    #Iterate over the val images while saving the frames and masks in appropriate folders
    dir_name='val'
    for file in zip(frames_list[-round(0.2*len(frames_list)):],masks_list[-round(0.2*len(masks_list)):]):
        
        
        #Convert tensors to numpy arrays
        frame = frame_batches.next().numpy().astype(np.uint8)
        mask = mask_batches.next().numpy().astype(np.uint8)
        
        #Convert numpy arrays to images
        frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
        mask = Image.fromarray(mask)
        
        #Save frames and masks to correct directories
        frame.save(DATA_PATH+'{}_frames/{}'.format(dir_name,dir_name)+'/'+file[0])
        mask.save(DATA_PATH+'{}_masks/{}'.format(dir_name,dir_name)+'/'+file[1])
    
    print("Saved {} frames to directory {}".format(len(frames_list),DATA_PATH))
    print("Saved {} masks to directory {}".format(len(masks_list),DATA_PATH))
    
generate_image_folder_structure(frame_tensors, masks_tensors, frames_list, masks_list)

#generate_image_folder_structure(train_frames, train_masks, val_files, 'val')
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/khawar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/api/_v1/keras/models/__init__.pyc in <module>()
     48     print("Saved {} masks to directory {}".format(len(masks_list),DATA_PATH))
     49 
---> 50 generate_image_folder_structure(frame_tensors, masks_tensors, frames_list, masks_list)
     51 
     52 #generate_image_folder_structure(train_frames, train_masks, val_files, 'val')

/home/khawar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/api/_v1/keras/models/__init__.pyc in generate_image_folder_structure(frames, masks, frames_list, masks_list)
     13     #Iterate over the train images while saving the frames and masks in appropriate folders
     14     dir_name='train'
---> 15     for file in zip(frames_list[:-round(0.2*len(frames_list))],masks_list[:-round(0.2*len(masks_list))]):
     16 
     17 

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: Can you print `-round(0.2*len(frames_list))` before using it? Seems like it's what's causing the crash.

Comment: The output is -20.0